# Access Object in App Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a personal finance application in WPF.  I have my MainWindow which obviously handles the rendering.  My question is, how do I elegantly access an object in the App class?  My structure is set up like this:

```
class Application { }

class App : Application {
  private AccountManager accountManager;  // HOW DO I ELEGANTLY ACCESS THIS IN MAINWINDOW?  
                                          // USE SINGLETON PATTERN?
}

class MainWindow { }

class AccountManager {
  List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
}

static class AccountFactory {
  static Account CreateFactory(string Account);
}

class Account { }
class Asset : Account { }
class Equity : Account { }
class Expense : Account { }
class Income : Account { }
class Liability : Account { }
```

Comment: delete all that "factory" stuff. C# is not java. you don't need millions of useless abstractions. Keep it simple.

Comment: Can you elaborate how the Factory design pattern is strictly Java and not C#?

Comment: @keelerjr12 Is the Factory design pattern nesessary? The provided snippet does not show the nesesserity of this pattern here.

Comment: @keelerjr12 basically, java sucks and is a retarded worthless dinosaur while C# is a properly designed, modern language.

Comment: That said, simply put the string parameter in the constructor of the account class, if anything. Or use object initializers and leave constructors alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a member of one class from another class you make this member `public`. Keep in mind that public fields are generally bad idea, so use public property:

```
public AccountManager accountManager { get; private set; }
```

The setter is private, so the property will be read-only for `MainWindow` class. 
Thanks @ HighCore for the readability tip.

Comment: Is the best way to do this?  I usually fall into the "getters & setters" are bad design category.

Comment: @keelerjr12 Nobody can say 'this is the best way to...'. It's always depends. I believe **in this case** nothing is wrong with using of property with private setter. The good thing is the simplicity of resulting code.

Comment: please. for the love of all that is good, put the getter first. Your code makes me want to kill little kittens. `{ get; private set; }`

Comment: @HighCore Just curious what is the difference

Comment: @MadSorcerer the difference is that all C# code written in the entire history of humanity has getters first, and so people's brain EXPECT it to be that way, which means that quickly reading your code I interpret `{ private get; set; }` instead.

Comment: @HighCore Thanks, fixed that. Please, don't kill the kittens.